# Bind simple json to MVC Form Collection

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3, data-binding, knockout.js

I'm trying to bind a simple json object (just key value pairs) to an MVC form collection or something of the sort

JavaScript:

```
function CMSModel() { 
    var self = this;

    self.Enable = ko.observable(true);
    self.CMSAddress = ko.observable();
    self.CMSAddressExtension = ko.observable();
    self.Username = ko.observable();
    self.Password = ko.observable();
    self.Protocol = ko.observable();
    self.Port = ko.observable();
    self.Interval = ko.observable();
    self.Area = "CMS";

    self.SubmitCMS = function () {

        //Validate numbers

        $.ajax({
            url: "/config/@Model.Model/" + self.Area,
            contentType: "application/json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            data: ko.toJSON(self)

        });
    }
 }
```

And this is what I would like on the MVC side:

```
    public ActionResult CMS(FormCollection fc)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Json:

```
{"CMSAddress":"asdf","CMSAddressExtension":"asf","Username":"asdf","Password":"asdf","Protocol":"HTTP","Port":"123","Interval":"123","Area":"CMS"}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to automatically bind a simple key value pair of json to a form collection. I don't want to create an object to bind the json with because I need to be more flexibility to dynamically create them based on some other information.

Thoughts as how I can do this?

Anything is greatly appreciated,

Matthew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you will need to create a custom binder, that will automatically bind the data to the IDictionary.

The Binder

```
public class DictionaryModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        //get the posted JSON
        var request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var jsonStringData = new StreamReader(request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
        //use newtonsoft.json to deserialise the json into IDictionary
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string,string>>(jsonStringData);
    }
}
```

You should register the binder in Global for IDictionary<> type. There are also other ways to register the binders.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...other logic
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(IDictionary<string, string>), 
                              new DictionaryModelBinder());
    ...other logic
}
```

And finally, you should be able to use IDictionary<>. This will be bound to all the properties you will pass from ajax

```
    public ActionResult YourAction(IDictionary<string, string> values)
    {
        ... your logic here
    }
```

Comment: This works well, but for some reason, it does not properly bind to ko.toJSON(self). The data looks the same (both valid json) but for some reason it does not turn into key value pairs like manually typing it in. 

Works with:

{ "cms_address": self.CMSAddress }

Does not work with:

ko.toJSON(self) which results in 

{"CMSAddress":"asdf","CMSAddressExtension":"asdf","Username":"asdf","Password":"asdf","Protocol":"HTTP","Port":"asdf","Interval":"asdf","Area":"CMS"}